# modules couldn't be hot updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to get hot reloading working in my React app but I'm not sure how to go about debugging this error.

[image]

My application index looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Routes from 'routes/index'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import syncHistoryWithStore from 'modules/routing/sync'

function createStore (browserHistory) {
  let factory = require('./modules/store')

  const store = factory.createStore(browserHistory)

  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./modules/store', () => {
      const nextFactory = require('./modules/store')
      nextFactory.hydrateStore(store, factory.dehydrateStore(store))
      factory = nextFactory
    })
  }

  return store
}

const store = createStore(browserHistory)
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store, {
  selectLocationState: state => state.routing,
  adjustUrlOnReplay: true
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <Routes history={history} store={store} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

The error occurs when I try to modify any of my react components. Those updates come through the `routes/index` path. But I don't understand why the [react-redux-universal-hot-example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/redux/create.js), from which I've taken ides, works and mine doesn't?

I can see that in the hot-example only the 'reducer' path has a `hot.accept` so I don't quite understand how got reload of react components work, but they just do...

Any suggestions or ideas how to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if I combine it with react-hot-loader:

```
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Routes from 'routes/index'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import syncHistoryWithStore from 'modules/routing/sync'

function createStore (browserHistory) {
  let factory = require('./modules/store')

  const store = factory.createStore(browserHistory)

  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./modules/store', () => {
      const nextFactory = require('./modules/store')
      nextFactory.hydrateStore(store, factory.dehydrateStore(store))
      factory = nextFactory
    })
  }

  return store
}

const store = createStore(browserHistory)
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store, {
  selectLocationState: state => state.routing,
  adjustUrlOnReplay: true
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <AppContainer>
    <Routes history={history} store={store} />
  </AppContainer>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./routes/index', () => {
    // If you use Webpack 2 in ES modules mode, you can
    // use <App /> here rather than require() a <NextApp />.
    const NextRoutes = require('./routes/index').default
    ReactDOM.render(
      <AppContainer>
        <NextRoutes history={history} store={store} />
      </AppContainer>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    )
  })
}
```

However, I still don't understand how the hot-reload example can work?